# Lake McKenzie turning green?

Tags: australia, lakes, queensland

One of the most magnificent tourist destinations in the world is the largest sand island in QLD Australia, called Fraser Island.

On it you can visit a crystal clear fresh lake, called Lake McKenzie. It used to look like this:

[image: Lake McKenzie]

On a recent trip however, I was disappointed to see it had a dirty green colour.

Does this happen cyclicly or is it permanently green these days? What is the cause of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dirty color was likely the result of sunscreen, soaps, lotions, etc... combining with the high acidity of the lake water. It was likely a local occurrence that you ran into as most of the lake is still extremely clear.

One other thing... the color does change between green and blue based on time of day and other factors... perhaps what you saw was natural?